# Understanding virtual table in multiple inheritance

Tags: c++

I have a class implementing two abstract classes, like the following. No virtual inheritance. No data member.

```
class IFace1 {
public:
    virtual void fcn(int abc) = 0;
};

class IFace2 {
public:
    virtual void fcn1(int abc) = 0;
};

class RealClass: public IFace1, public IFace2 {
public:
    void fcn(int a) {
    }

    void fcn1(int a) {
   }
};
```

And I find the vtable and object memory layout for RealClass is like the following.

```
Vtable for RealClass
RealClass::_ZTV9RealClass: 7u entries
0     (int (*)(...))0
8     (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI9RealClass)
16    (int (*)(...))RealClass::fcn
24    (int (*)(...))RealClass::fcn1
32    (int (*)(...))-8
40    (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI9RealClass)
48    (int (*)(...))RealClass::_ZThn8_N9RealClass4fcn1Ei

Class RealClass
    size=16 align=8
    base size=16 base align=8
RealClass (0x2af836d010e0) 0
    vptr=((& RealClass::_ZTV9RealClass) + 16u)
    IFace1 (0x2af836cfa5a0) 0 nearly-empty
        primary-for RealClass (0x2af836d010e0)
    IFace2 (0x2af836cfa600) 8 nearly-empty
        vptr=((& RealClass::_ZTV9RealClass) + 48u)
```

I am confused about this. What is RealClass::_ZThn8_N9RealClass4fcn1Ei? Why the vptr of IFace2 points to that? What happens when I call fcn1 from IFace2 *? How does the program finds RealClass::fcn1 in the Vtable of RealClass? I guess it somehow need to use the IFace2 vptr, but not clear exactly how.

Comment: There are many ways of implementing this. A good, well-documented one is http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/cxxabi-1.83.html (but it may not match the one you're using).

Comment: Try looking at  the code generated for such a call?

Comment: RealClass::_ZThn8_N9RealClass4fcn1Ei is a `RealClass::non-virtual thunk to RealClass::fcn1(int)` which is probably intended for inlining and other call optimizations. Hint: `c++filt` program is your friend.

Comment: I think the RealClass::_ZThn8_N9RealClass4fcn1Ei is the magic function gcc put to direct function call to RealClass::fcn1. When we make call to fcn1 using a IFace2*, it simply call the function that is pointed by its vptr

Answer (score 4):

*Warning: Most of the stuff below is of course implementation and platform dependent and simplified. I'll follow the way I see it is implemented in your examples -- probably GCC, 64-bits.*

---

First, what is the contract for instances of virtual classes? E.g. if you have a variable `IFace1* obj`:

- There is a pointer to virtual table at **obj+0**.
- Any member data fields would continue at **obj+8** (`sizeof(void*)`).
- The virtual table contains one record which points to `void fcn(int)` at **vtbl+0**.
- In the table, there is also a pointer to `typeinfo` of the class at **vtbl-8** (used by `dynamic_cast` etc.) and "*offset to base*" at **vtbl-16**.

Any function which sees a variable of type `IFace1*` can depend on this being true. Similarly for `IFace2*`.

- If they want to call the virtual function `void fcn(int)`, they look at **obj+0** to get the vtable, then at **vtbl+0** and call the address found there. `this` is set to **obj**.
- If they want to access a member field (by themselves, e.g. if the field has public access, or if there is an inline accessor), they just read/write the member at its address **obj+xxx**.
- If they want to see what type they really have, they subtract the value at **vtbl-16** from the address to their object, then look at the `typeinfo` pointer of the vtable referenced by the base object.

---

Now, how can you compiler satisfy these requirements for a class with multiple inheritance?

**1)** First it needs to generate the structure for itself. The virtual table pointer must be at **obj+0**, so there it is. How will the table look like? Well, the *offset to base* is 0, obviously, the `typeinfo` data and pointer to it is generated easily, then the first virtual function and the second, nothing special. Anyone who knows the definition of `RealClass` can do the same calculations, so they know where to find the functions in the vtable etc.

**2)** Then it goes to make it possible to let `RealClass` be passed around as `IFace1`. So it needs to have a pointer to virtual table in the `IFace1` format somewhere in the object, then the virtual table must have that one record for `void fcn(int)`.

The compiler is clever and sees that it can reuse the first virtual table it has generated, because it complies with these requirements. If there were any member fields, they would be stored after the first pointer to the virtual table, so even them could be accessed simply as if the derived class was the base one. So far so good.

**3)** Finally, what to do with the object so others will be able to use it as `IFace2`? The one vtable already created cannot be used anymore, because `IFace2` needs its `void fcn1(int)` to be at **vtbl+0**.

So another virtual table is created, the one you see immediately following the first one in your dump, and a pointer to it is stored in `RealClass` at the next available place. This second table needs to have *offset to base* set to -8, because the real object starts at offset -8. And it contains just the pointer to that `IFace2` virtual function, `void fcn1(int)`.

The virtual pointer in the object (at offset **obj+8**) would be then followed by any member data fields of `IFace2`, so that any inherited or inline functions could again work when given the pointer to this interface.

---

OK, now how can someone call the `fcn1()` from `IFace2`? What is that `non-virtual thunk to RealClass::fcn1(int)`?

If you pass your `RealClass*` pointer to a stranger function which takes `IFace2*`, the compiler will emit code to increase your pointer by 8 (or however large `sizeof(void*) + sizeof(IFace1)` is), so that the function gets the pointer which starts with the virtual table pointer of `IFace2`, then its member fields -- just as agreed in the contract I outlined earlier.

When that function wants to call `void IFace2::fcn1(int)`, it looks into the virtual table, goes to the record of this particular function (the first and only one) and calls it, with `this` set to the address being passed as pointer to `IFace2`.

And here arises a problem: If someone invokes this method implemented in `RealClass` on a `RealClass` pointer, `this` points to the base of `RealClass`. The same with `IFace1`. But if it is invoked by someone having a pointer to the `IFace2` interface, `this` points 8 (or however many) bytes into the object instead!

So the compiler would need to generate the function multiple times to accomodate this, otherwise it could not access member fields and other methods correctly, as it differs depending on who is calling the method.

Instead of having the code really twice, the compiler optimizes this by creating that hidden implicit small **thunk** function instead, which just

1. decreases the `this` pointer by the proper amount,
2. calls the real method, which can now work fine regardless of who invoked it.